# CSS Display:Inline-block mis-aligns when multi line text is present

Tags: css

Everything looks and works fine as the jsFiddle shows, but if you add enough text to the LOGIN SECTION box, to make the text split across multiple lines, it pushes the outer 2 header blocks out of alignment. It appears as though if I add text in the center box, the outer boxes appear to drop to the line where the text ends. I.E - Make "login section" repeat for multiple lines and it pushes the outer boxes down.

Link to correct jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d7xXB/

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="headerblock">Logo 1 Here</div>
<div class="headerblockmiddle">Login Section Login Section Login Section Login Section Login Section</div>
<div class="headerblock">Logo 2 Here</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
width:800px;
min-height:550px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:#FFF;
margin-top:10px;
padding: 5px;
position:relative;
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
body {
background-color: #2a8dba;
}
.headerblock {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
display:inline-block;
height: 85px;
width: 200px;
background-color:#CCC;
padding: 0px;
/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
.headerblockmiddle {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
display:inline-block;
height: 85px;
width: 370px;
background-color:#CCC;
padding: 0px;
/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Nevermind! I fixed it by adding; vertical-align: top; to the headerblock class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the vertical alignment of the inline block elements to top.

```
.headerblockmiddle {
    ...
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d7xXB/2/

Comment: thanks! I had just done that myself and was trying to delete my post (I added a comment to my post to say I'd fixed it with veritcal-align: top)
Thanks for your quick response and will accept your answer when it lets me in 5mins.